# Disable authentication on CORS preflight requests

Tags: asp.net-core, http.sys

I'm running an Http.sys web server Windows Service that requires authentication. The API endpoints are being called from a site hosted in IIS.

CORS configuration on the API service:

```
var corsOrigins = configuration.GetSection("AllowedCorsOrigins").Get<string[]>();
builder.Services.AddCors(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b =>
    {
        b.WithOrigins(corsOrigins)
         .AllowCredentials()
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});
```

Further down:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

HttpSys configuration:

```
builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
    options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
    options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    if (prefixes?.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var prefix in prefixes)
        {
            options.UrlPrefixes.Add(prefix);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem appears to be that the negotiation mechanism fails during the preflight request and the browser doesn't receive the expected headers, which the browser interprets as a CORS error ("No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.").

Is there a way to disable authentication on preflight requests *without* explicitly adding OPTIONS endpoints for all API methods?

Comment: Your CORS middleware seems to be layered at the correct place. Does `corsOrigins` actually contain valid Web origins? A common misconfiguration is to specify URLs (with a path, etc.) rather than Web origins (scheme, host, optional port).

Comment: Yes, it does. The problem isn't that the origin isn't set on the appropriate header, it seems that *no headers are set* because it fails authentication (it shouldn't try to authenticate anyway, it's an OPTIONS request).

Comment: To me, that sounds like middleware out of order...